# Documents to make for larger appspot projects

Tags: software-development, process, documentation

My appspot projects are growing and I'm making an SDD ("system design document") and an RAD ("requirements analysis document") for every larger project I deliver (currently 2 and 2 others are also growing.)

Am I doing the right thing? I follow the structure for the documents as mentioned in the book Object-Oriented Software Engineering by Bernd Bruegge and Allen H. Dutoit.

Thanks

Comment: What objective are you trying to accomplish by generating these documents? Are you distributing it to customers or other developers?

Comment: Maybe a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are doing the **right** thing when:

- your colleagues read the documents you wrote and find it useful
- reuse the knowledge written done in the upcoming/next projects
- customer asked for it
- you are paid for it - this is your full time job
- customer support finds it useful

you are doing the **wrong** thing when:

- create documentation because a book said so
- you are only one who contributes and cares